# Public variable getter shows as transaction in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.5.x, local-variables, solidity-0.6.x

As of Solidity 0.6.0+  compiler, my remix shows getter functions, built by public variables, as transactions and, therefore, do not return the value. I searched the [solidity 0.6.0 breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.1/060-breaking-changes.html) but I didn't find any explanation to this. What am I missing?

Example on solidity pragma <=0.5.16:
[image]

Example on solidity pragma >=0.6.0:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the [ABI JSON](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abi-spec.html#json) produced by the compiler and how the tools use it to determine if a function is `view` or `pure`.

As you can see in the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/abi-spec.html#json):

> The fields `constant` and `payable` are deprecated and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the `stateMutability` field can be used to
>   determine the same properties.

Now, see how different are the JSON generated using the following simple contract:

```
contract C1 {

    uint x;

    function setX(uint _x) public {
        x = _x;
    }

    function getX() public view returns (uint) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Please, note that only the ABI for the `getX()` function is shown.

---

[JSON format for v0.6.0](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/abi-spec.html#json)

```
{
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getX",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
```

---

[JSON format for v0.5.13](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.13/abi-spec.html#json)

```
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "getX",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
},
```

**EDIT:**

As we can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/d3f75c88a193f0b302a35d13ad12b59ab49cf407/src/app/ui/universal-dapp-ui.js#L148), Remix used only the `constant` field to determine if a function is `view` or `pure`.

```
var lookupOnly = args.funABI.constant
```

Now, this is solve, as we can see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/master/src/app/ui/universal-dapp-ui.js#L148).

```
const lookupOnly = args.funABI.stateMutability === 'view' || args.funABI.stateMutability === 'pure' || args.funABI.constant
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for the well-detailed answer

Comment: I do not think that “probably remix use the field constant but I cannot confirm that” be a so definitive answer to justify to mark the question as “answered”. Upvote it if it is useful, but if you mark it as “answered” nobody will finish the work.

Comment: @RickPark I'm agree, so I updated my answer with that information.